# Can I write assertions for Artillery Load Test results?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am using [Artillery](https://artillery.io/) for load testing my rest APIs. I want to write assertion for the artillery results using mocha. Is it possible?

Comment: See https://artillery.io/docs/http-reference/#advanced-writing-custom-logic-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using javascript.

In artillery script, use afterResponce:  and write code to assert there.

```
"get": {"url": "host/path",
                                    "headers": {
                                        "Content-Type":"application/json"
                                    },
                                    "afterResponse": "function_name"
                                }
```

write function_name in a separate js file and add assertion to that function.

Import that js file in artillery script as below

```
"processor": "./my_function.js"
```